# Vote to close illegible on meta

Tags: bug, design, meta

The vote to close is illegible here on meta:

[image]

(as is the image upload)

Comment: I have already started a similar thread [here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/changing-colours-of-meta?rq=1). But maybe it needs the added attention of two threads.